# loadUserByUsername() is not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to wire up an application running on spring boot and spring security. However when I key in my credentials in the login(credentials are correct, queried from database), I observed that the loadUserByUsername() is not invoked.

This is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
    <head>
        <title>SMUA Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>SMUA Login page</h1>
        <form action="@{/login}" method="post">
            Email:
            <input type ="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            Password:
            <input type ="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            <!--<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />-->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the DAO:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package smua.models.DAO;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import smua.models.Entities.AppLookup;
import smua.models.Entities.Demographic;
import smua.models.custom.CustomDemoDetails;

/**
 *
 * @author r128
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DemographicDAO implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<AppLookup> retrieveAllByPlace(String semanticPlace) {
        return getSession().createQuery("from LocationLookup").list();
    }

    public void batchCommit(HashMap<String, Demographic> demographicMap) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Iterator<Demographic> demographicMapIter = demographicMap.values().iterator();
        int counter = 1;

        while (demographicMapIter.hasNext()) {

            Demographic curDemographic = demographicMapIter.next();
            session.save(curDemographic);
            if (counter % 30 == 0) { //30, same as the JDBC batch size

                session.flush(); //flush a batch of inserts and release memory
                session.clear();
            }
            counter++;

        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    //get Demographic Object method
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Email is : " + email);
        String hql = "from Demographic where email = :email";
        Demographic demographic = (Demographic) getSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email);
        if(demographic == null){
            System.out.println("User does not exists");
            //remember to import Exceptions
        }
        return new CustomDemoDetails(demographic);
    }
}
```

and here is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package smua.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

/**
 *
 * @author twjAm
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SmuaWebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, 
                UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .and()
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("123456")
                .roles("ADMIN");


    }

    /*private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
        return repository;
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

        /*
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
        */
    }

}
```

and according to Spring, I have added the following files so that the application will load the security configuration.

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package smua.configs;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

/**
 *
 * @author famous
 */
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

and MvcWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package smua.configs;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 *
 * @author famous
 */
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SmuaWebSecurityConfigAdapter.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}
```

So yeah, i've been looking up guides and stuff online but to no avail. Furthermore, the application compiles and deploys without errors so its hard to pinpoint problem. Hope you guys could shed some light on this (:

Comment: When using memory authentication you basically are using a user repository in memory. So spring has no reason to hit the db or to call your provided service. All it needs is allready available in ram.

Comment: @DirkLachowski hey there! Thanks for the reply! Well, i've removed the user I previously defined in memory and ran the application again, but still the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method couldn't be reached.